# How to Implement activity transition animation in Android Studios

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, android-studio, android-animation

How can we use transition animations between 2 activities in android studios.We would be normally using a button and when clicked opens a new activity using an intent.Now how can we use transition animations between this two activities adding to the fact that i am very beginner in android studios and i please expect the answer to be a bit more clear.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

res/anim/

activity_fade_in.xml  :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
   android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0"
   android:duration="500" />
```

activity_fade_out.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
   android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0"
   android:fillAfter="true"
   android:duration="500" />
```

In Activity or Fragment:

```
 startActivity(intent);
 overridePendingTransition(R.anim.activity_fade_in,R.anim.activity_fade_out);
```